# Get variables from Main Controller

Tags: java, controller, javafx-8

I am creating a board game with JavaFX. I have two controllers for my project and would like to access variables and methods from the main controller.  My main controller has most of the game logic and UI but I would like to have a popup window for special cases.  Right now I have the popup window, but would like to use variables from the main controller in the popup window controller.  I was able to get variables from the secondary controller to the main controller but not the other way around.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code in the main controller that opens the new popup window:

```
public void newWindow() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("player.fxml"));
            //Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage playerStage = new Stage();
            playerStage.setTitle("Pick your move");
            playerStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            playerStage.setScene(new Scene((Pane) fxmlLoader.load()));
            playerStage.show();
            ControllerPopup controller =
                    fxmlLoader.<ControllerPopup>getController();
            this.controller = controller;
            if(currentCard.getMoves() == 10){
            controller.handleTen();
            }
            else if(currentCard.getMoves() == 11){
            controller.handleEleven();
            }
            else{
            controller.handleSeven();
            }
            disablePawns(bluePawns);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here is the secondary controller:

```
public class ControllerPopup implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private RadioButton button1,button2,button3,button4;
    @FXML
    private Button closeButton;
    private RadioButton selectedButton;
    private ToggleGroup group;
    Controller controller;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        group = new ToggleGroup();
        button1.setToggleGroup(group);
        button2.setToggleGroup(group);
        button3.setToggleGroup(group);
        button4.setToggleGroup(group);
    }

    public void handleTen(){
        button1.setSelected(true);
        button1.setText("Move forward 10");
        button2.setText("Move backwards 1");
        button3.setDisable(true);
        button4.setDisable(true);

    }

    public void handleEleven(){
        button1.setSelected(true);
        button1.setText("Swap with another pawn");
        button2.setText("Move forward 11");
        button3.setDisable(true);
        button4.setDisable(true);
    }

    public void handleSeven(){
        button1.setSelected(true);
        button1.setText("Move forward 1 and 6");
        button2.setText("Move forward 2 and 5");
        button3.setText("Move forward 3 and 4");
        button4.setText("Move forward 7");
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleCloseButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        selectedButton = (RadioButton) group.getSelectedToggle();
        Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();


    }

    public RadioButton getSelectedButton(){
        return selectedButton;
    }
```

Comment: Which variables do you want to access? Why can't you just pass their values from the main controller to the "secondary" controller: `controller.setXXX(...);`?

Comment: Yep that solved it! Thanks.. Don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the appropriate set methods in the "secondary" controller and pass the values to them from the main controller:

```
controller.setXXX(...);
```